# Solve window is not Function in React after build

Tags: reactjs

Hello everyone I got a problem

I tried to use window calling function from react to Index HTML

but after build it didnt work

How can I solve that

Im tried to use window in REACT

In React Like :

```
`window.test = () => {  
 console.log("Calling Function")
}`
```

And HTML Is :

```
`<button id="test">Click me</button>

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('click' , function(){
    window.test()
})
`
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Remember to look at your post after submitting: this is not how you mark up blocks of code. [Use triple-backticks with language indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/markdown#syntax-highlighting) for code blocks. Also, remember that `window` only exists in the browser, but much more importantly: don't use `window`. If you need a function that you can call from various places, create a file and put the function in there with an `export` statement so you can just `import` it wherever you need it.